Can’t get past blue screen loops
I can’t even reinstall windows from usb, even though it’s selected in bios. Everytime I restart the system, the “Mag” msi logo will pop up, it will buffer shortly and throw up different blue screens each failure ranging from “kmode exception not handled” “kernel failure” etc. I’ve tested the RAM,the m.2 everything is fine, the stick with windows is fine and works on other PC’s. The processor is an intel i9 13900k. I just want it to boot windows one way or another; please note when the pc was working windows update would fail to update recent updates.

The motherboard or chipset could be dead. I am puzzled though, seems you never access the USB boot stage, so it could also just be windows. If you start the computer and directly after start, hold the powerbutton to force shut it down, and do this 3 times, you should be able to boot from usb.

Will update if this worked within an hour, have to run some errands but will double check that the usb is priority in bios, and attempt to force boot to safe mode as you described above. Thank you for your response

I did not say force boot to safe mode. It boots you to the UEFI rescue menu, where you can access the bios and select the boot menu in order to boot from USB drive.

Update: I do not ever access usb boot stage; I held the power button down directly after start 3 times and it still gave BSoD “kmode_exception_not handled”. So let’s presume it is just windows.. how do I get windows off of this m.2 if I can’t boot in safe mode or boot from usb? I wish I could format it from bios but there’s no option

You can unplug the m.2 and see if that allows you to boot the USB, and before you say: but then I can't install windows, yes, I know. The idea here is just to test that it is the windows installation, and not a hardware problem. If you can boot the USB normally, and no blue screens, its windows, if you can't, its probably the motherboard. If it is indeed windows, find a way to erase the m.2, and the BSoD problem should go away. You do have backups, right?

You can also test another OS, to prove if it's a hardware issue or not. Try making a Ubuntu Live USB, select it in BIOS. BTW, on some boards, one must select the USB drive in Boot Order, not just in BIOS. (On this PC, F2 is BIOS, but I must use F12 to change boot order.)

Update: erased the m.2 and the problem persisted, restored factory bios settings, and did a clean install of windows 11 on it and no luck, my next step will be lowering the cores to 1 to test if the processor is the problem, if it works on 1 core I guess I’ll have to RMA it. If it still doesn’t work I’ll test the board at microcenter. I do not believe it is a OS problem as I’ve attempted installation of windows 10 and windows 11 with separate sticks for each. I’ve also noticed two different blue screens including kernel thread exception and wdf.01000.sys
